# Gradle 2 - CopySpec properties for custom plugin

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am writing a custom plugin for Gradle 2.0 which extends AbstractArchiveTask. I wish to add some properties to the CopySpec closure, e.g.

```
task myCopy(type: CustomCopy) {

  propertyA = 'cheese'

  into 'destDir'

  from('srcDir')


  from('otherSrcDir') {
    into 'otherDestDir'
    propertyA = 'Beef'
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to add these properties to both the task and the inner closure?

How would I then get these properties in my CopyAction and CopyActionProcessingStreamAction implementations?

Thanks in advance

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, there wasn't a way to achieve this with public APIs. Perhaps have a look at the `Rpm` task implementation of https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin. As you can see in its [docs](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/blob/master/Plugin-Rpm.md#example), that task adds new properties in both the locations you mentioned.